# Imagick doesn't resize vector GIFs correctly PHP

Tags: php, gif, imagick, vector-graphics

I'm using imagick for image uploads and resizing. when I try to resize GIF image with vector graphics it won't resize as original. but normal animated giphys are woring. please advice

https://giphy.com/explore/vector-design
 these giphs are not resizing with correct animation.

below is my code.

```
$imagick =  new Imagick($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

foreach ($imageFolders as $imageFolder => $size) {

    if ($imagick->getImageWidth() > $size['minWidth']) {
        $width = $size['maxWidth'];
        $height = $size['maxWidth'];
    } else {
        $width = $imagick->getImageWidth();
        $height = $imagick->getImageHeight(
    }

    $imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();

    foreach($imagick as $frame){
        $frame->thumbnailImage($width , $height ); 
        $frame->setImagePage($width , $height , 0, 0); 
    }

    $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();
    $imagick->writeImages($imagePath, true);

}

$imagick->clear();
$imagick->destroy();
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "vector GIF" -- GIF is a bitmap format. What happens when you try to resize these images?

Comment: @duskwuff : I 'm refering about https://giphy.com/explore/vector-design  these type of gifs . when i'm resizing it doesnt produce the exact, most of the time it borke the effects.

Comment: It says _"Explore vector design GIFs"_ there, with the _"vector design"_ even offset in different color ... so they are talking about the visual image content (lines, shapes, ...) here, not the file format ... duh!

Comment: @CBroe : https://media.giphy.com/media/8WUoenZqLZclO/giphy.gif but this kind of images ? so aren't these support with imagick? pls advice

Comment: Well first of all, that's not an image at all, that URL returns an _HTML document_, that itself embeds the image as an external resource (don't say you tried to feed _that_ into IM ...?), and, at least in my Chromium-based browser, the actual image is not a GIF, but a WebP image - https://i.giphy.com/media/8WUoenZqLZclO/giphy.webp ... those support animation as well, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP#Animated_WebP